# Why are the contents of the span next to the div appearing on different lines?

Tags: html

I have this basic structure in html but it the contents are showing up in two lines but I want them to be on the same line right beside each-other. Replicated in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/entropy283/pen/jOBbXjx)

```
<div>
 <span>span</span>
 <div>div</div>
</div>
```

How do I get those two elements to display the text next to eachother?

Also when copying and pasting the text it should match the inline structure

Answer (score 0):

You can use two spans, or if you need to use a div for the second element, you can use `style="display: inline-block"`

```html
<div>
    <span>span</span>
    <span>div</span>
</div>

<div>
    <span>span</span>
    <div style="display: inline-block">div with inline block</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` is a block element and will always show on its own line by default. To change that

```
<div style='display:inline'></div>
  <!-- or -->
<div style='display:inline-block'></div>
```

or in your `<style>` tag

```
div {
 display:inline-block;
}
```